# Is there a way to get new access token when current session get expired without using Connected App?

Tags: authentication, connected-apps, .net, refresh-token

I have one Customer's Salesforce Application and one .Net Web Service.
I also have Connected App in Salesforce which I am using to generate new token.

Salesforce Application calls .Net Web Service and pass session id and refresh token.
.Net Web Service uses session id for authentication while interacting (using http request) with Salesforce.

I have logic in .Net Web Service to get new access token when current session id get expired using refresh token.

Now, I want to remove dependency of Connected App because of some reasons. 
So I want to know is there any way to get new access token without using Connected App?

Answer (score 1):

> Now, I want to remove dependency of Connected App because of some reasons. So I want to know is there any way to get new access token without using Connected App?

**No**. You will always need to provide the Client Id/Secret along with the refresh token to get the new access token. And for that purpose you will need your Connected App to be active. Take a look at [How Does the OAuth Refresh Token Fit Into the Authentication Flow?](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_refresh_token_oauth.htm) to get more details as what are the attributes which are required in the refresh token flow.

However, you don't necessarily need the Connected App to be available in the same Org where your services are connecting to. You can always utilize a Connected App (and thus Client Id/Secret) from one Org and still be able to authenticate to another Org using that information as long as you have the correct authentication details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SOAP [login](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login.htm) API to authenticate with username/password, it does not require a connected app. The SOAP call will return a session ID.